# CSS move relative positioning div to outside the overflow hidden div

Tags: css, overflow, css-position

I have to do move a div to overflow hidden parent div. I use some plugin on the page. So I can't change divs ordering. I want to move green box over the blue and red box. I hope there is a solution.

https://jsfiddle.net/bigboytr/zssub946/

Important note : If I change the parent divs position attribute, plugin not working properly.

```css
#box1 {
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

#box2 {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#box3 {
  position: relative;
  background: green;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box1">
  <div id="box2">
    <div id="box3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, your question should contain a [**Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Where's your code? (Hint: it should be **in** your post, not offsite.)

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I change my post. I hope this is ok.

Comment: Better, though I placed in it a Stack Snippet which is even more useful. BTW, a `div` is not self closing like a `input` or `img`, it needs a closing tag.

Comment: yes, I know divs are not self closing. I was just  fast typing. edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Move box2 overflow attribute to box1.
2. Give padding to box1.
3. Give negative value to box3 to pop out.

```css
#box1 {
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#box2 {
  position: absolute;
  background: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#box3 {
  position: absolute;
  background: green;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  top: -5px;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="box1">
  <div id="box2">
    <div id="box3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
#box1 { position: absolute; background: red; padding: 5px; width: 150px; height: 150px; }
#box2 { position: absolute; overflow: hidden; background: blue;  width: 100px; height: 100px; }
#box3 { position: relative; background: green; width: 50px; height: 50px; top: -10px; }

#box3 {
      /* left 150px (box1) - box3 width 50px = 100px */
      z-index: 2; padding: 0; top: -5px; left: 100px }
#box2 { overflow: visible }
```

```html
<br/><br/><br/>
<div id="box1">
  <div id="box2">
    <div id="box3"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/xmct0wot/

Changes were necessary to box2 and box3:

```css
#box3 { width: 160px; height: 160px;
      /* 160px because width, height = 150px plus 5px + 5px padding */
      z-index: 2; padding: 0; top: -5px; left: -5px }
#box2 { overflow: visible }
```

Comment: Where's the markup? You're using a  Stack Snippet, might as go all the way.

Comment: Your advice isn't what I'm looking for. Now green box override other boxes.

Comment: Sorry thought you wanted it over top from your description-- you want it in the top right of red?.. did you end up getting it there?